# HTTPS request Memory leak with CurlAsyncHTTPClient

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, tornado, pycurl

My handler file

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys
from tornado import gen, web, httpclient

url = "https://mdetail.tmall.com/templates/pages/desc?id=527485572414"

class SearchHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        async_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        print sys.getrefcount(async_client) # The first time less than 10, then always bigger than 200
        req = httpclient.HTTPRequest(url, "GET", headers=headers)
        req_lists = [async_client.fetch(req) for _ in range(200)]
        r = yield req_lists
        print sys.getrefcount(async_client) # always bigger than 200
        # The longer req_lists, the more memory will be consumed, and never decrease
```

configure file

```
tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(client, max_clients=1000)
```

if my client is **"tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient"**, Then when I visit my handler in broswer, **htop** shows memory increase about 6GB,as long as the process running, memory usage never decrease

If I set **range(200)** to **range(500)** or higher, Memory usage grows higher

if my cline is **None**, memory barely increase

I found only fetch the **https://** will have memory issue

How can I slove the momory problem with **CurlAsyncHTTPClient**?

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 16.10 x64
python2.7.12
Tornado 4.5.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference counts you see are expected, because with [`max_clients=1000`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.simple_httpclient.SimpleAsyncHTTPClient.initialize), Tornado will cache and reuse [1000 `pycurl.Curl` instances](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/d4094a0c2a7cddc654381c162ee7786d4bf8453b/tornado/curl_httpclient.py#L45), each of which may [hold a reference](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/d4094a0c2a7cddc654381c162ee7786d4bf8453b/tornado/curl_httpclient.py#L314-L316) to the client’s `_curl_header_callback`. You can see it with [`objgraph.show_backrefs`](https://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/).

Do you really need `max_clients=1000` — that is, up to 1000 requests in parallel? (I’m hoping they’re not all to the same server, as in your example!)

Anyway, the `Curl` instances seem to be taking up a lot of memory.

On my system (Ubuntu 16.04), I can reproduce the problem when using PycURL linked against the system-wide libcurl3-gnutls 7.47.0:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v python getter.py 
6
207
^C
[...]
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4853544
```

When I link PycURL with a freshly built libcurl 7.54.1 (still with GnuTLS backend), I get a much better result:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/curl-prefix/lib /usr/bin/time -v python getter.py 
6
207
^C
[...]
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1016084
```

And if I use libcurl with the OpenSSL backend, the result is better still:

```
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 275572
```

There are other reports of memory problems with GnuTLS: [curl issue #1086](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1086).

So, if you do need a large `max_clients`, try using a newer libcurl built with the OpenSSL backend.

Comment: Thank you very much, But I still don't understand why only **"https://"** requests consume huge memory with **CurlAsyncHTTPClient**, but **"http://"** requests don't

Comment: @zpoint As I said, the high memory usage seems to be related to the TLS backend used by libcurl (GnuTLS vs. OpenSSL). Of course, TLS is only used for HTTPS, not for plaintext HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, I will try latest version of libcurl